# DataFrame - Unique values

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
table<-data.frame(col1=c("ab ac", "ac", "ab", "ab ab", "ab","ac ac ac", "aa aa ab","aa ab ac"))

      col1 
1    ab ac    
2       ac   
3       ab   
4    ab ab   
5       ab   
6 ac ac ac  
7 aa aa ab    
8 aa ab ac
```

And I want to create another column with unique values if there is only one value or if exists two or three similar ones or, in the other hand, the number of different values in each column.

```
table<-data.frame(col1=c("ab ac", "ac", "ab", "ab ab", "ab","ac ac ac", "aa aa ab","aa ab ac"),col2=c("2","ac","ab","ab","ab","ac","2","3"))

      col1 col2
1    ab ac    2
2       ac   ac
3       ab   ab
4    ab ab   ab
5       ab   ab
6 ac ac ac   ac
7 aa aa ab    2
8 aa ab ac    3
```

Can someone help me with this task.

Comment: Try and avoid naming your dataframes after existing R functions ( like `table`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
table %>%
    mutate(colN = col1) %>%
    rownames_to_column("rn")  %>% 
    separate_rows(colN) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(col1 = first(col1), 
              col2 = n_distinct(colN),
              col2 = replace(col2, col2==1, unique(colN))) %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#      col1  col2
#    <fctr> <chr>
#1    ab ac     2
#2       ac    ac
#3       ab    ab
#4    ab ab    ab
#5       ab    ab
#6 ac ac ac    ac
#7 aa aa ab     2
#8 aa ab ac     3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one idea,

```
sapply(strsplit(table$col1, ' '), function(i) ifelse(length(unique(i)) > 1, length(unique(i)), i))
#[1] "2"  "ac" "ab" "ab" "ab" "ac" "2"  "3"
```